# Impact of array size on performance

Tags: go

I just started learning Go and I found myself creating a simple program that:

- Creates an `int` array of size `SIZE` (expected to be >= 1000)
- Iterates through its elements from 0 to 999, setting them to 0
- Prints how long everything took

Something like this:

```
package main

import (
    "time"
    "fmt"
)

const SIZE = 1000

func main() {
    start := time.Now()
    a := [SIZE]int {}
    for i := 0; i < 1000; i++ { a[i] = 0 }
    fmt.Println("Time: ", time.Since(start))
}
```

I got the following results after running on my machine 5 times:

- `3.375µs`
- `2.831µs`
- `2.698µs`
- `2.655µs`
- `2.59µs`

However, if I increase `SIZE` to `100000` (100x) the program becomes slower. These are the observed results on the same machine:

- `407.844µs`
- `432.607µs`
- `397.67µs`
- `465.959µs`
- `445.101µs`

Why is the value of `SIZE` making such a big difference? The number of iterations will always be the same (1000)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### In one sentence

> Because you are also counting the time to allocate the slice

#### Explanation

In your code, you are creating the `start` variable just before your big slice `a`.

```
func main() {
    start := time.Now()
    a := [SIZE]int {}
    //...
}
```

By doing this, you are ignoring the fact that allocating a slice with `1000` items is much faster than allocating a slice with `100000` items.

You have to move this initialization after the allocation. The size of the slice should not affect the time to loop through it up to a certain number of (equal) iterations.

In my [benchmarks](https://play.golang.org/p/U722waScZBv):

```
| Items  | ns/op | Count slice allocation? |
|--------|-------|-------------------------|
| 1000   | 1411  | YES                     |
| 100000 | 66565 | YES                     |
| 1000   | 837   | NO                      |
| 100000 | 855   | NO                      |
```

Comment: Cool! I just assumed that allocating space wouldn't take a considerable amount of time, which is not the case here. Thanks for the detailed answer!